# DocumentApp service throws a "Service Documents failed while accessing document with id" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am creating a script for Google Docs, that takes every element from the current doc I'm in and copies it into another document (basically making a copy).

```
duplicateDocument();

function duplicateDocument() {
  var currentDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.create('Speech Doc');
  var totalElements = currentDoc.getNumChildren();

  //Goes through each type of element to preserve formatting
  for( var index = 0; index < totalElements; ++index ) {
    var body = targetDoc.getBody();
    var element = currentDoc.getChild(index).copy();
    var type = element.getType();

    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      body.appendTable(element);
      }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      body.appendListItem(element);
      }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.BOOKMARK ){
      body.appendBookmark(element);
    }
    } 
}
```

As soon as I call the function, this error pops up:

**Service Documents failed while accessing document with id [id of target doc]**

This code worked a day or two ago... what gives?

Comment: My script creates a new document, called 'Speech Doc'. The ID in the error matches up with the ID of the new doc that is created. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: It doesn't specify a line; it just says theres an error accessing the doc. The doc ID is for the doc titled 'Speech Doc,' so I assume it's referring to this line: var targetDoc = DocumentApp.create('Speech Doc'); OR this one: var body = targetDoc.getBody();

Comment: For some reason the debugger just disappears after showing that error. It doesn't specify what line it just says it can't access the speech doc.

Comment: Oh I was just thinking that perhaps you have use saveAndClose() first and also get the id before you that so that you can access in  the rest of the code.

Comment: The first line shown is `duplicateDocument();` Is this an actual code line in your proyect?

Comment: I tried your code and everything seems to work just fine. If you have indeed the line `duplicateDocument();` it will create two files but a part from that this should work. Could you try to rerun and see if this is working for you now?

Comment: I tried to rerun it. Same error shows up. I submitted a bug to google, but I'm also going to go ahead and try it on a different google account. Also, the line `duplicateDocument();` is just calling the function called "duplicateDocument"

Comment: Maybe share a sample of doc file that is giving you this error so I can run the code in your file myself. This seems to be something up with your file/account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was me adding a footnote into the document I wanted to duplicate.

After removing the footnote, it duplicated the document just fine.

Edit: I opened an issue on Google's [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158310285)